# How can I skip a file from import if file doesn't exist?

Tags: matlab, import

tarFileNames contain the names of all files that need to be imported. Some of the files may not exist. How can I skip over the files that don't exist so that the loop doesn't stop with this error:

```
Error using imread (line 349)
File "C:\Users\xyz.tif" does not exist.
```

Code:

```
for m = 1:length(tarFileNames)
    tarConus = imread(tarFileNames{m});
    tarConus(end,:) = []; % Dropping last col and row from each page 
    tarConus(:,end) = [];
    tarAccum = plus(tarConus(select),tarAccum); 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the presence of a file using [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). Be sure to specify the second input argument which specifies that you want to look for files by that name only.

```
%// Determine all of the files that don't exist.
doesExist = cellfun(@(x)exist(x, 'file') == 2, tarFileNames);

%// File which do not exist
invalidNames = tarFileNames(~doesExist);

%// File which do exist
validNames = tarFileNames(doesExist);

%// Only loop through the ones that do exist
for m = 1:numel(validNames)     
    tarConus = imread(validNames{m});
    tarConus(end,:) = []; % Dropping last col and row from each page 
    tarConus(:,end) = [];
    tarAccum = plus(tarConus(select),tarAccum); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I am guessing this is more efficient computationally than the solution below (which matters to me due to the large dataset)?

Comment: Also, can I get a list of files that have been skipped?

Comment: @maximusdooku Updated.

Answer (score 2):

`exist()` can check whether files exist or not. This ought to do it:

```
for m = 1:length(tarFileNames)
    if exist(tarFileNames{m}, 'file')
        tarConus = imread(tarFileNames{m});
        tarConus(end,:) = []; % Dropping last col and row from each page 
        tarConus(:,end) = [];
        tarAccum = plus(tarConus(select),tarAccum);
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get a list of files that have been skipped?

Comment: you could use an `else` statement (before the first `end`) to store the current `tarFileNames{m}` string into a cell, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

`if exist(Name, 'file')` returns 2 if a file exists or 7 if a folder exists.

sorry, currently no matlab available to write and test the full code for you.

I guess it should be something like that:

```
for m = 1:length(tarFileNames)
    if exists(tarFileNames{m}, 'file')
       tarConus = imread(tarFileNames{m});
       tarConus(end,:) = []; % Dropping last col and row from each page 
       tarConus(:,end) = [];
       tarAccum = plus(tarConus(select),tarAccum); 
    else
    end
end
```